# install.packages does not deal with whitespace in file path

Tags: r, windows

A simple change in the example vignette from [this site](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/vignettes/miniCRAN-introduction.html) illustrates my problem.

The code below will run. No problem. Because there is no whitespace in the url.

```
#miniCRAN example
library("miniCRAN")

# use Revolution Analytics CRAN mirror
revolution <- c(CRAN = "http://cran.microsoft.com")

# Specify list of packages to download
pkgs <- c("foreach")
pkgList <- pkgDep(pkgs, repos = revolution, type = "source", suggests = FALSE)
pkgList


# Create temporary folder for miniCRAN
dir.create(pth <- file.path("C:", "RTEMP", "miniCRAN"), recursive=TRUE)


# Make repo for source and win.binary
makeRepo(pkgList, path = pth, repos = revolution, type = c("source", "win.binary"))


# List all files in miniCRAN
list.files(pth, recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE)


#install packages from your local repository
install.packages(pkgs, repos = paste0("file:///", pth), type = "source")
```

But if we change the following line so it has a space character, then it will fail on install.packages.

```
# Create temporary folder for miniCRAN
dir.create(pth <- file.path("C:", "WHITE SPACE", "miniCRAN"), recursive=TRUE)
```

Looks to me like the pth string gets split up. Is there any way around this, other than changing folder names in my filesystem? I tried to replace " " with "%20" but that did not help. I am on a Windows system, btw.

```
Warning: invalid package 'C:/WHITE'
Warning: invalid package 'SPACE/miniCRAN/src/contrib/foreach_1.4.4.tar.gz'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
```

Comment: I would try `shortPathName(file.path("C:/", "WHITE SPACE", "miniCRAN"))`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent   Could you write this up as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I think `file.path("C:", "WHITE SPACE", "miniCRAN")` is not valid path, because there's no slash after `C:`.

Anyway, to use `install.packages` with a path containing white spaces, use `shortPathName`:

```
shortPathName(file.path("C:/", "WHITE SPACE", "miniCRAN"))
```

Comment: We do not need the "/" after "C:" because it is the path separator added by the file.path function.